# Detect which other modules are enabled in a new Drupal module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm creating a Drupal module which doesn't necessarily depend on other modules, but could offer other options if, for example, the Path module is enabled.

What I'd like to know, and can't seem to find by searching, is whether it is possible to detect which modules are currently enabled from another module so that that module can offer options which use those modules?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- http://api.drupal.org/api/function/module_exists/6
- http://api.drupal.org/api/function/module_list/6

You can also check like this:

```
if(function_exists('a_function_you_know_the_module_provides')) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for that - crazy that I couldn't find it on any searches through the drupal site or google...